# error : X struct has no member named Y

Tags: c, struct

Please share some light upon this error i'm getting ...
So I have a file, let's name it myFile.c, where I have this method

```
STATUS deleteCom(pPCM_128 pMain)
{
    DELETE_SEM(pMain->open.tOpenSem);
}
```

and this header file, myFile.h in which I have a main struct that contains lots of other structs. The main struct contains a struct named 'open' as you can see below.

```
typedef struct main_struct
{
    /* other members*/

    struct
    {
        int nOpen;      
        int rOpen;      
        SEM_ID  tOpenSem;
        SEM_ID  rOpenSem;
    } open;

} MAIN_STRUCT;

typedef MAIN_STRUCT     PCM_128 ;
typedef MAIN_STRUCT*    pPCM_128 ;
```

When I compile the project, I get this error :

```
..\myFile.c:100: error: 'MAIN_STRUCT' has no member named 'open'
```

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: The code you pasted is just fine. The problem is somewhere else. Try isolating blocks of code to pinpoint the exact piece of code that triggers the problem.

Comment: Show us more code please.

Comment: I have tried giving my nested struct a name, as suggested, but I still receive the same error ... Thanks anyway !

Comment: @Tzoma That's because, as other comments says, there's no error in the code you have posted.

Comment: @nouney ... I receive same errors for all the members (for structs similar to 'open') inside the MAIN_STRUCT ... "MAIN_STRUCT has no member named config / sync " etc. I thought it's redundant to post more code ...

Comment: Which is line 100? Are you sure you have included the header?

Comment: Line 100 is : DELETE_SEM(pMain->open.tOpenSem) and the header is included of course :)